# Latest version of Angular: Images load on localhost but not when deployed on firebase or amazon S3

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, amazon-s3, deployment

Hey guys I'm trying to host my angular application and everything was working perfectly fine when loading images onto a template but when I host it on either an AWS S3 or on Firebase they both have the same result and don't load. The images are stored in a MongoDB and recovered as a base64 image,they are then loaded onto the image tag with the following code:

```
<a><img class="image-category" [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+categories[i].thumbnail" (error) = "filename = '../../assets/default-category.png'" /></a><br>
```

I've kind of ran out of ideas I don't really know what else to try any help would be appreciated.

**Local Host Output**
[image: Firebase Output]
**FireBase or S3 Output**
[image: Localhost Output]

Also the images are being loaded asynchronously so I wrote a check method to keep checking whether they all finished loading.

```html
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { GetcategoriesService } from 'src/app/services/getcategories.service';
import { Categories } from 'src/app/classes/categories';
import { ImageuploadService } from 'src/app/services/imageupload.service';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.scss']
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  categories: Categories;
  filename: string;
  tempImg: string;
  initialized = false;
  catinitialized = false;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private getCategoriesService: GetcategoriesService, private imageUploadService: ImageuploadService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategories();
    const source = interval(500);
    this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.initializeImages());
  }

  initializeImages(){
    if (this.catinitialized)
    {
      try{
        console.log(this.categories);
        for (const index of this.categories)
        {
          console.log(index);
          this.imageUploadService.getFile(index.thumbnail).subscribe(
          (image) => {
            index.thumbnail = image['pic']['data'];
            console.log(index.thumbnail);
          });
        }
        this.initialized = true;
        console.log(this.initialized);
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }catch (e){}
    }
  }

  getCategories()
  {
    this.getCategoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(
      (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.categories = response;
          this.catinitialized = true;
          console.log('Finished loading...');
      }
    );
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Here's the html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="initialized==true" class="row">
        <div class="image-container justify-content-center col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let category of categories;let i = index;">
            <a><img class="image-category" [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+categories[i].thumbnail" (error) = "filename = '../../assets/default-category.png'" /></a><br>
            <a><h1 class="label-category">{{category.name}}</h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And lastly the scss

```html
.container{
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-category{
    border-radius: 5%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.label-category{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide online version of your project if it possible?

Comment: Sure this one is on S3 : https://storestaticbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html it's a little buggy cause of S3 but just click on categorias and you'll see the error

Comment: you had a not full url for your image